# is it possible to use IF condition inside mysql Query?

Tags: mysql, if-statement, prompt

Is it possible to use `IF` condition inside a MySQL query? If so can you please explain, with a simple example how.

Comment: There is documentation for this software.

Comment: You can find it here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on your mysql prompt.

```
> mysql> create table t(i int);
>
> mysql> insert into t values(1),(2),(3);
>
> mysql> select i, if(i <= 1, 'low', 'high') from t order by i;
> +------+---------------------------+
> | i    | if(i <= 1, 'low', 'high') |
> +------+---------------------------+
> |    1 | low                       |
> |    2 | high                      |
> |    3 | high                      |
> +------+---------------------------+
> 3 rows in set (0.06 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to do there are a couple of options.

For a single query, look at [CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html) syntax.

If your using stored procedures look at [IF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if-statement.html) syntax.